# How do I set/clear the Windows archive bit with cygwin’s find/chmod?

Tags: windows, cygwin

Yes, I know, the archive bit is evil.

That being said, is there support for querying it with 'find', and modifying it with 'chmod'?

My googling has turned up nothing......

Comment: actually it's not.  the evil bit is evil: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3514.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `find` + `attrib`:

```
$ find . -option whatever -exec attrib -A {} \;
```

[`attrib`](http://www.easydos.com/attrib.html) is the old DOS command for setting & clearing those attributes.  This works for me on WinXP Pro SP2; no idea if `attrib` is still available on Vista/Win-7.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution that will work in all situations, however, on NTFS file systems, first edit your [CYGWIN environment variable](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html), adding ntsec.  On NTFS you can then use chmod to [manage file permissions](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-files).  This variable is typically set in `/../cygwin/cygnus.bat`.  When setting CYGWIN, separate each option with a space.

I'll try to figure out a working example cmd line...